# use for loop inside python fabric automation

Tags: python, fabric

How to use for loop inside fabric defination

```
expample:


  Create number of  ipspace:

  ips_total=raw_input("Enter numper of ipspace required:")
  for x in range(1,ips_total):
  print"network ipspace create -ipspace ipspace{}".format(x)
```

Inside  fabric def i want use for loop or any other way i can achieve this

say when user enter 4

```
  from fabric.api import *
  def ipspace():
      run("network ipspace create -ipspace ipspace1",shell=False)
      run("network ipspace create -ipspace ipspace2",shell=False)
      run("network ipspace create -ipspace ipspace3",shell=False)
      run("network ipspace create -ipspace ipspace4",shell=False)
```

Since we dont know what number user enter so its better to use for loop logic inside fabric. could any one please help to implement this

Answer (score 0):

So, may I change a little bit  `ipspace` so that it will take as argument the many times it should be run?

```
from fabric.api import *
def ipspace(n):
    for i in range(n):
        run("network ipspace create -ipspace ipspace" + str(i+1),shell=False)
```

Comment: Hi Jefferson, def ipspace(n): is not working i used ipspace() so it works that great.

Comment: If you want to read from a variable, you should pass it to the function somehow. I tried with an argument, which in turn implies that all callers should be changed to give `n` to `ipspace`. Another way is to declare this is a method from an object that has some `n` as a property, or maybe you can use `n` as a global resource so that it is accessible from both `ipspace` and the point that reads the user input